# how to nginx configuration updates without having to reload or restart nginx

Tags: nginx

I want Nginx to update configuration file without reloading or restarting Nginx. It seem API or anything (http://nginx.com/products/on-the-fly-reconfiguration/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Ubuntu or Debian it's as simple as using the `reload` argument:

```
service nginx reload
```

The official way is to send SIGHUP:

```
kill -HUP $(ps -ef | grep nginx | grep master | awk '{print $2}')
```

The above command will get the process ID of the nginx master process and send a SIGHUP signal to it.

See the [Controlling Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#reconfiguration) documentation for Nginx.

You can also use the Nginx binary:

```
nginx -s reload
```

Comment: FYI, the `-s reload` command is documented here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/switches.html.

Comment: What's the difference between `systemctl nginx reload` and `nginx -s reload`?